# Verbs describing a state or situation: passive form

Tags: verbs, passive-voice, aspect

"English Grammar Today" book says that "We don't usually use the passive with some verbs that describe a state or situation." If this is an actual rule, why, for example, have I found a lot of occurrences of "[lunch was being had](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22lunch+was+being+had%22&hl=it&client=ms-rim&channel=browser&oq=%22lunch+was+being+had%22&gs_l=mobile-heirloom-serp.12...0.0.0.20376.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1ac.Mybasxb76KI)"?

Is the book wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verbs that describe a state or situation are generally intransitive verbs, and passive constructions can only be formed with transitive verbs. Having lunch is an act rather than a state or situation, and *have* in this context is transitive, making a passive construction possible.

Comment: Also I'd say that "lunch was being had" in general is probably pretty poor style

Comment: @ssb. Perhaps, but that's another matter.

Answer (score 2):

The book is right.

In the first place, as Barrie England reminds you, only transitive verbs can take a passive construction, and most verbs which ‘describe a state or situation’ are intransitive.

In the second place, the book doesn’t say ‘never’ or all verbs’, just ‘usually’ and ‘some verbs’.

And your counter-example is marginal.  *Have lunch* is does not necessarily ‘describe a state or situation’; usually it describes an act. Even in the progressive forms it describes an act in progress rather than a state.

Besides, ‘a lot of occurrences’ is a relative term. Even that *Circa 590 risultati* Google estimates is pretty thin; if you go to actually look at them you find there are only 42; and when you eliminate the duplicates and copies, you’re down to just 22 actual utterances across the entire internet.

I’m not a fan of Google NGrams, but crude as it is, [here](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lived+a+life%2Ca+life+was+lived%2Cloathed+it%2Cit+was+loathed&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)'s the sort of thing your book is talking about: ‘lived a life’ and ‘loathed it’ against their passive versions

[image]